# CountDownTimer inside fragment: manage pause and resume fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I have a fragment with a CountDownTimer object and i would pause timer when fragment goes in background, then resume it when fragment comes again into foreground. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    active = false;
    try {
        synchronized (countDownTimer) {
            countDownTimer.wait();
            Log.i("TIMER", "wait");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (countDownTimer != null) {
        countDownTimer.notifyAll();
        Log.i("TIMER", "notify");
    }
}
```

In that way, timer stops countdown when i put fragment into background, but don't restart when i recall into foreground. What's wrong?

Comment: This tutorial explains [How to pause and resume CountDownTimer](http://androidsolution4u.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-count-down-timer.html). Just try to implement it in fragment's onPause() and onResume().

Comment: I don't have implement a new class for timer, but if i try to create a new CountDownObject inside onResume, eclipse says that i cannot instantiate the type countdown timer...